# Block Play Store crawler from parts of app

Tags: android, google-play, web-crawler, robots.txt

We're developing a Unity plugin to be used by third-party apps. During our own testing, we've found that Google Play Store's automatic crawler (apparently called Robo) activates the plugin and clicks around at random, causing contamination of our results. This will be a big problem later on if every third party app causes the same contamination on every new release.

My question is then, is there any way to prevent the crawler from going down a certain path? Like a robots.txt but for apps? The solution can't really rely on the third-party developer configuring their own Play Store either. I've been searching all morning but have not come up with any viable solution.